# Instances of shared library on android

Tags: android, shared-libraries

There is a shared library with static variables and functions I want to use in both Flex and Java. So my Flex application loads the library through an ANE file, the Java through JNI (though it is the exact same library). Does Android load 2 instances of the library for each application or does it use the same instance for every app using it?

For example: The library has a static integer variable that is assigned to 0 when created. Flex changed that integer to a 3. What result will Java give if the Java code reads that variable. A 0 or the 3?

Comment: Are you saying that you have two separate applications (one Flex, one Java), or that you have combined a Flex and a Java code base into one application?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated, I have one Flex application which has a native extension to Java. Java communicates with the shared library to do some stuff. But after Java is done I want to access methods of the library from Flex without the Java in between. So technically they are two different applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So technically they are two different applications

If they are two different applications (e.g., would have two separate entries in the Play Store), then they will run in separate processes. Each app will have a copy of the JNI code; each process will load its own copy of that JNI code. Nothing will be shared between them, any more than if the two applications were installed on separate devices.

Comment: I see. But is it possible for Flex and Java to use the same instance of the loaded library?

Comment: @WesselvanderLinden: Only if they were running in the same process, and even then I'm not sure that it's possible.